# How to use navigator.app.exitApp()?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an application built in html5 and phonegap for android, by pressing the exit button I call the following function(JavaScript):

```
function close_window() {
    if (confirm("Exit?")) {
        navigator.app.exitApp()
    }
}
```

Window with the message "Exit?" appear, but the application does not close when you click OK, how can we close it?

Is this the way to use navigator.app.exitApp()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your missing with call of `confirm` notification.

Please try following code, it is working fine in my app:

```
document.addEventListener("exitButton", function(){ 
              navigator.notification.confirm(
                        'Do you want to quit', 
                        onConfirmQuit, 
                        'QUIT TITLE', 
                        'OK,Cancel'  
                    );
            }, true); 

    function onConfirmQuit(button){
       if(button == "1"){
        navigator.app.exitApp(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
   if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {        
    alert("No network connection");
}
}
```